# Maze Game, creating 2D array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays

I have College's project where I should create a maze game(player, different type of gifts, different type of walls..etc ). one of the requirements is 
"You have to make a 2D array of objects (entities) where entities can be a player/wall/bomp/gift"- I do not get that one? what's useful about creating 2D array of objects?. Thanks

Comment: "what's useful about creating 2D array of objects?" - this question would be easier to answer in a helpful way if it were contrasted to an alternative approach that you think is more useful.

Comment: Useful?? rather that's useless cause in that case you will end up doing lots of casting/boxing. Instead you should consider using generic 2D array or a 2D array of base type.

Comment: I don't think "2D array of objects" actually refers to the data type, but rather to the concept of an object as an instance of a class. Type is free to be chosen by what is most convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you create a 2D array of objects which represents the "world" of the maze. A player is in a certain spot in the maze represented by his coordinates (for instance [4, 7]) his movements are constrained by the walls around him, and events are represented when he is moved onto bomps/gifts/etc.

example (P = player, W = wall, B = bomp, G = gift):

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWW
W  W        W
W  W  WWW  WW
W  W  WGW   W
W  W  W W P W
W     B W   W
WWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

Now, in this example the player is in index [4, 10], and he can move any direction.

If he decides to move left one space he will be in index [4, 9] and our 2D array will now look like this:

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWW
W  W        W
W  W  WWW  WW
W  W  WGW   W
W  W  W WP  W
W     B W   W
WWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

now he may move up, right and down, but he cannot move left.

I suppose that when a player moves onto the index of a bomp or a gift (in our cases when the player is in [5,6] he has encountered a bomp and in [3,7] he will encounter a gift) some event is supposed to occur (for example: when he encounters a bomp he cannot move for 2 seconds, when he encounters the gift he wins the game).

I hope I understood your question correctly and have answered it.

Answer (score 0):

When you are talking about a 2D array of objects, it means you are subconsciously thinking about one of the most powerful aspects of object oriented programming which is called polymorphism. In this case all of the visual cells of your field are grouped in 4 different Objects. A cell is nothing more than a bomb,gift,wall or player so you can consider that a cell object is the parent of all these types, so you can easily treat them similarly.
For example suppose that you are  going to show a public simple message if your index tries to pass the wall or a bomb or a gift. Would you like to implement this method for every cell or once for all cells? 
I think the major advantage of having a 2d array of objects or your customized objects is the ability to manage and control the whole array similarly when they are trying to show their different behavior.

```
 abstract class Cell
  {
        public virtual void passCell()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yo have been trying to pass a cell");
        }
  }

class Bomb:Cell
 {
    public override void passCell()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have been trying to pass Bomb Cell !");
    }
 }

class Gift:Cell
 {
    public override void passCell()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have been trying to pass Gift Cell !");
    }
  }
class Wall:Cell
 {

 }

 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Cell[] cellArray=new Cell[3];
            cellArray[2]=new Bomb();
            cellArray[1]=new Gift();
            cellArray[0]=new Wall();
            for (byte i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                cellArray[i].passCell();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

**Out Put :**

1-You have been trying to pass a Cell.

2-You have been trying to pass a Gift Cell!

3-You have been trying to pass a Bomb Cell!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object[,] entities = {
                    { new Player(), new Wall(), new Bomp(), new Gift()},
                    { new Player(), new Wall(), new Bomp(), new Gift()},
                    { new Player(), new Wall(), new Bomp(), new Gift()},
                    { new Player(), new Wall(), new Bomp(), new Gift()}
            };

        }
    }
    public class Player
    {
    }
    public class Wall
    {
    }
    public class Bomp
    {
    }
    public class Gift
    {
    }
```